# How can I normalize the time series in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

The goal is to create the time series normalized on the first value of the time frame. For example, we have the series

```
time                 | value
------------------------------
2020-07-13T00:00:00Z | 2
2020-07-14T00:00:00Z | 4
2020-07-15T00:00:00Z | 3
```

and want to get the result

```
time                 | value
------------------------------
2020-07-13T00:00:00Z | 1
2020-07-14T00:00:00Z | 2
2020-07-15T00:00:00Z | 1.5
```

I have tried the following query:

`select "value" / first_value from (select "value" from "database"."autogen"."measurement"), (select first("value") as first_value from "database"."autogen"."measurement")`

but it produces empty time series.

Could somebody explain me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired outcome can be achieved by adding `fill(previous)` at the end of your query i.e.

```
select "value" / first_value from (select "value" from "database"."autogen"."measurement"), (select first("value") as first_value from "database"."autogen"."measurement") fill(previous)
```

...which gives the following output:

```
name: measurement
time                 value_first_value
----                 -----------------
2020-07-13T00:00:00Z 
2020-07-13T00:00:00Z 1
2020-07-14T00:00:00Z 2
2020-07-15T00:00:00Z 1.5
```

It seems that for the `"value" / first_value` calculation to take place values in both fields have to exist at the same timestamp. Since the result of the subquery `select first("value") as first_value from "database"."autogen"."measurement"` provides a single value at a specific timestamp, the requirement is not met. However, `fill(previous)` makes `first_value` available at the required timestamps.